# Как сделать стартовую страницу на динамической дирректории?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет. 
В проекте стоит задача, в котором стартовый URL должен начинаться с абривеатуры языка.
По типу такого:

> https://stackoverflow.com.**ru**./ 
>   Вопрос:
>   Каким способом корректнее всего выполнять такую задачу?
>   Что делать со статической страницей стартовой?
>   (делать с нее редиректы на динамическую языковую страницу?)
>   Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Я предлагать с помощью $_COOKIE

Comment: 1. Подскажите, как определяете язык пользователя? 2. Почему динамическая? У Вас же должна быть на другом языке страница. Или Вы планируете перевод _"на лету"_?

Comment: Язык пользователя определяю из заголовка браузера на лету.
(само собой еще будет опция выбора языка в дополнение)
А как на статической вы предлагаете это реализовывать?